# Where can I find the story of Magic the Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-lore

I have been playing MTG for a few months now and was told that there is a story behind each set of cards.  I have several small bits of the story that came with the decks, but I would like to read the full story and see if I can construct my themed decks to match how they would be in the story. Where can I learn more about the back-story to these cards?

Comment: you can also get an insight into each set's setting by the flavor text of the cards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wizards has short storyline summaries shown here:

http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/products/storylinesummaries

Unfortunately, this is an old page and hasn't been updated since Mirrodin.

Wikipedia has a fairly comprehensive outline of [Magic: The Gathering storylines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic%3a_The_Gathering_storylines) that are helpful in getting a handle on the general theme of each set.

However, if you want to get a handle on affiliations of specific characters and creatures within their settings, I highly recommend starting at the MTG Salvation wiki [Category:Storylines](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Category%3aStorylines).

Answer (score 13):

I don't read them myself, but every year Wizards of the Coast releases novels which are a companion to the latest Magic sets/block.  If you want the complete "story behind the game", this is probably the best path to go down.

Here's a useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_novels

The Magic Daily site also has quite a fun column called "Savor the Flavor" which contains essays on the latest sets from a storytelling and flavour perspective - you can't get a full picture of what's going on from reading it, I don't think, but it may appeal to someone who is interested in the ongoing story aspect of Magic, not just the mechanics of the game:

http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Archive.aspx?tag=SavortheFlavor&description=Taste%20the%20Magic

Answer (score 3):

The Wizards of the Coast website has a page within it that contains the full story, minus the novels. Heres [the link](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/columns/magic-story).

Comment: The provided link currently 404s.